# Capturing and processing a live RTMP stream

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-streaming, rtmp, live-video

I'm trying to download a **live stream** (not a file) coming from a live camera feed available at the following website: http://www.dot.ca.gov/video/.

I used Wireshark for sniffing the TCP packets and was able to extract the RTMP parameters, but wasn't able to use them with FFMPEG/VLC for downloading / playing the stream on VLC (I guess I didn't construct the URL correctly).

for example, for the camera feed available [here](http://www.dot.ca.gov/d4/d4cameras/ct-cam-pop-E37_at_Lakeville_Rd.html/), I got the following parameters:

1. swfUrl: http://www.dot.ca.gov/research/its/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf
2. pageUrl..Ehttp://www.dot.ca.gov/d4/d4cameras/ct-cam-pop-
   N17_at_Saratoga_Rd.html
3. tcUrl: rtmp://wzmedia.dot.ca.gov:1935/D4
4. Play : E37_at_Lakeville_Rd.stream.

Is there a chance someone is familiar with this and can help with understanding how I can use the above for downloading the stream?

Thanks a lot!
Yaniv

Answer (score -1):

You only need the RTMP url (which is combined from the server connection url and stream name).
Use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://wzmedia.dot.ca.gov:1935/D4/E37_at_Lakeville_Rd.stream your_output.mp4
```

or open vlc with the RTMP url.

[More about RTMP url format.](https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/60/rtmp-single-url-format-server-url-and-stream-name.html)

Comment: Why? May be some explanation.